# Determine a and b so that function is continious

Tags: calculus, functions

$$
g(t)=
\begin{cases}
2t^2 ;& t<-1 \\
at ;&-1<t<1 \\
bt-\frac 12 ;&t>1
\end{cases}
$$

How can I determine $a$ and $b$ so this function $g$ is continuous at whole $\mathbb R$.

I am confused by this 3. unknown $t$.

Comment: What do you mean with "3."?

Comment: How $g(t)$ is defined at $t=\pm1$?

Comment: As written, this function is continuous in its domain of definition, no matter what $a$ and $b$ are. And it cannot be continuous "at whole $Bbb R$" because it is not even defined at whole $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have solution for this example. And they have specific values for a and b. But I dont know how to get them.

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic The problem is:_ If the problem statement appears *exactly* as you copied it, then it is ill-posed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points that may cause discontinues are $t=1$ and $t=-1$. $g(t)$ is continues  at $t=1$ iff $\lim_{t\to1}g(t)=g(1)$. It is suffices to demand that
$$
\lim_{t\to1^{-}}g(t)=\lim_{t\to1^{+}}g(t)=g(1), 
$$
that is 
$$
\lim_{t\to1^{-}}at=\lim_{t\to1^{+}}\left(bt-\frac{1}{2}\right)=g(1). 
$$
which yields the following equation 
$$
a=b-\frac{1}{2}=g(1)
$$
Similarly, for $t=-1$ we get the following equation 
$$
2=-a=g(-1)
$$
Hence $a=-1$ and $b=-\frac{3}{2}$. If we want $g(t)$ to contibues we have to define $g(1)=-2$ and $g(-1)=2$

Answer (score 1):

As the right and left limit in point $t=-1$ should be equal, you have $2=-2a\rightarrow a=-2$. After finding $a$,

As the right and left limit in point $t=1$ should be equal, you have $-2=b-1/2\rightarrow b=-3/2$.